# Replace # with \u0023 in a Java String

Tags: java, string, replace

Replace `#` with `\u0023` in a Java String which looks like below:

> {subjectCategory:"s123", subjectId:"111222333", content:"test #comment999", ownerId:"111", ownerName:"tester"}

```
String.replace("#","\\u0023");
```

I've tried the above function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? What do you want to achieve and what is the result of using this function?

Comment: Please clarify what you want? **a)** Input:`#`, desired output:`\u0023` or **b)** Input:`\u0023`, desired output:`#`

Comment: I want to replace # by \u0023

Comment: @sagarvikani We know that already. Please give us more information or post an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
string = string.replace("#", "\\u0023");
```

Test:

```
String s = "hello # world";
s = s.replace("#","\\u0023");
System.out.println(s); // prints hello \u0023 world
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't forget to assign to a variable**:

```
String toUse = myString.replace("#", "\\u0023");
```

Probably, you expect to use same string after `replace()` call. But, strings are **immutable**, so a new string will be created with `replace()` call. You need to use it, so use `toUse` variable.

**Note:** As said in comments, you can also use old variable again, instead of declaring new one. But ensure to assign result of `replace` call to it:

```
myString = myString.replace("#", "\\u0023");
```

Comment: @sagarvikani What do you mean with "doesn't work"? What do you want to achieve and what is the result of using this function?

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace `#` with `\u0023`. May be you want to replace `\u0023` with `#`?

Comment: You don't need to use a new `String` variable. You can just use the old `myString` agagin.

Comment: @Baz: It was just for clarification. I will edit my answer to reflect this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `replace` on the string instance you want to replace, not the static method in `String`:

```
myString="test #comment999";
myString.replace("#", "\\u0023");
```