# How to manipulate unicode characters in java

Tags: java, database, character-encoding

I want to replace "\u0023 \u0024 ab" 
with:
"\\u0023 \\u0024 ab" to maintain its encoding before storing it in database.

There can me many different values after \u, not just 0023, 0024.

I tried using str.replace("\"\\"); or ("\u","\\u") but it doesn't work in java because it treats \u0023 as one character.

Any suggestions how to achieve this ?

I tried like this

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "\u0023";       
        s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

but it is giving following output as:
#

but I am expecting:
\\u0023
```

Comment: There is no difference between both...

Comment: If your source string is `"\u0023 \u0023 ab"`, the occurences of `\u0023` *are* one character, namely `#`. So your source string is `"# # ab"`…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace # with \u0023 in a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791077/replace-with-u0023-in-a-java-string)

Comment: Please edit your question and wrap your examples with `code samples`. Currently I am not sure how many ``\`` your string contains because Stack Overflow also uses ``\`` as special character and escapes it which means that ``\\`` becomes ``\\``.

Comment: *which means that ``\\`` becomes ``\``.

Comment: To update your question use [edit] option (it seems that there is one pending edit suggestion so first you will need to accept or reject it). To create `code sample` use `{}` button in editors menu.

Answer (score 1):

As said by the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220366/get-unicode-value-of-a-character), you can retrieve the (numerical) unicode value of a character with:

```
// works up to Unicode 3.0
String hexString = Integer.toHexString(s | 0x10000).substring(1);
```

Using this number, simply print it out:

```
System.out.println("\u" + hexString);
```

(Note: code is untested: give me feedback if it doesn't work)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "\\u0023";       
s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: In his/her case: `"\u0023 \u0023 ab".replaceAll("\u0023", "\\\\u0023")`

Comment: Just indent your code with four spaces.

Comment: To avoid problems with ``\`` and `<...>` simply post your code as `code sample` (use `{}` button in editors menu). Don't post text as image.

Comment: there can be many different values after \u not not just 0023

Comment: @Bharthan: this code doesn’t depend on the actual number. As you should realize, there is no occurrence of the number in the arguments to the `replace` call.

Comment: @Holger: it is replacing \\ with \\\\ but my string only have single \

Comment: @Bharthan: do you *understand* Java code, i.e. escape sequences in strings? Or, alternatively, are you able to *try* it?

Comment: @MIK Like Bharthan is saying, I don't think this is answering the question: he has a `String` (unicode) representation of a character *with only one slash*. He wants to know how to print the unicode value with the given value with *only one slash*.

Comment: @Jonathan: please, try to understand [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), section “Escape Sequences” first. As I already said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379875/how-to-manipulate-unicode-characters-in-java/33380013#comment54553799_33379875), an occurrence of `\u0023` is a single character, i.e. `#`. Since it gets interpreted by the compiler, you can’t dissolve that single character at runtime. You (and the OP) have to understand the difference between an actual string contents ant it’s compile-time representation.